# When using R to link 2 data frames with a common column, how do I specify that it only link observations within a specific time interval?

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to link two data frames. One data frame (`STTest`) consists of strep throat testing for 100 individuals. The other data frame (`STCase`) consists of only those individuals who tested positive. I've included a snippet of each data frame below:

STTest

```
   patient_master_id   Testdate  
1         ID001         2011-07-16
2         ID002         2011-09-16
.....
```

STCase

```
  patient_master_id   reporteddate
1         ID001         2011-10-13
2         ID002         2011-09-27
...
```

I can link these cases based on both data sets sharing a common column that identifies patient IDs. However, I only need to link cases where the reported case is within 15 days of the testing date. What code do I use to set a condition where R will only link cases to tests within a specific time frame?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First check the class of the `Testdate` and `reporteddate` columns in STTest and STCase datasets respectively using class() function.

If it is not a date, first cast the columns to `Date`.

```
> STTest$Testdate <- as.Date(STTest$Testdate)
> STCase$reporteddate <- as.Date(STCase$reporteddate)
```

After that, merge the two datasets.

```
> int_ans <- merge(STTest,STCase)
> int_ans
  patient_master_id   Testdate reporteddate
1             ID001 2011-07-16   2011-10-13
2             ID002 2011-09-16   2011-09-27
```

Now, select the rows that satisfies the condition.

```
> int_ans[int_ans$reporteddate < int_ans$Testdate + 15,]
  patient_master_id   Testdate reporteddate
2             ID002 2011-09-16   2011-09-27
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try sqldf.

```
library(sqldf)

df1<-data.frame(patient_master_id = c('ID001','ID002'),
            Testdate= c('2011-07-16','2011-09-16'))

df1$Testdate<-as.Date(df1$Testdate)

df2<-data.frame(patient_master_id = c('ID001','ID002'),
            reporteddate= c('2011-10-13','2011-09-27'))

df2$reporteddate<-as.Date(df2$reporteddate)

window = 15

sqldf(paste("select A.patient_master_id, Testdate, reporteddate 
         from df1 as A INNER JOIN df2 as B
         WHERE A.patient_master_id = B.patient_master_id 
         AND (B.reporteddate - A.Testdate)<",window))
```

You can adjust the way of joining and time window to merge accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! This code correctly linked the reported dates to the appropriate test dates. But this command seems to have subsetted these three observations. Do you know how I would link it back to the rest of the merged data frame but at the same time not have the reported dates link back to earlier test dates from the same individuals?

Comment: @RSnow I'm not sure if I understand your question. Can you provide an example?